# How can a single member of the House derail a Congressional bill?

Tags: united-states, congress, house-of-representatives

I read a [news article](https://www.cbsnews.com/amp/news/disaster-relief-bill-house-will-try-again-to-pass-aid-package-derailed-by-lone-republican-congressman/) today that claims that a Congressional bill to provide disaster relief to US communities has been derailed, because a single member of the House of Representatives objected to it.

How is it possible for a single member of congress to effectively 'veto' an entire bill like this? I thought most (if not all) votes in Congress are decided by majority vote. Was this vote different for some reason, which meant it had to be unanimous? (if so, why?)

Comment: Comments are meant only for asking for clarifications or to suggest improvements. The couple of comments offering examples did neither, and were removed. Please do not re-post them.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The US house (and [other systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unanimous_consent)) allows for expedited voting via "[unanimous consent](https://archives-democrats-rules.house.gov/archives/voting_house.htm)" - without a proper vote where each member's position is noted, the Speaker simply asks for a voice vote and motions to pass with unanimous consent (which does not mean everyone votes "yes" but rather that anyone who would vote "no" effectively acknowledges that there are sufficient "yes" votes to pass, so they aren't going to waste their time).

However, any member can object to a measure passing this way, which is what happened in this case, and demand a full vote. This objection then delays the measure because it must be scheduled for a full vote.

Most reporting I have seen on the issue correctly describes this as a "delay" rather than a "veto" and indeed "delay" is a more appropriate description.

Comment: Wow, you would think Congress would be able to at least implement yes/no push buttons for this stuff, wouldn't you? Anyway, so it means the bill isn't dead, just that some time will be wasted as it has to go through a full majority vote?

Comment: @Time4Tea In this case it's in part because the House was in a pro forma session - there weren't enough folks around for a full vote. The reason Democrats have some reason to be upset here is that it doesn't seem like they had any indication there would be a problem here (i.e., the Republican leadership was on board, this is one member's doing). Frankly, even with all the bickering between the parties right now, most of the work the House does is non-controversial and passes by these simple votes. But yes, it is not completely dead, I've updated my answer to mention this is a delay.

Comment: It's also worth noting that this is _more_ of a delay than it would otherwise be, because the House is in recess.  Otherwise, they could just take the full vote immediately or the next day.

Comment: @Time4Tea You should see how the British vote on things, then.

Comment: @Time4Tea The House does have electronic push button voting (since 1973). The Senate does not.

Comment: "unanimous" - the proper term is *nem con* (*nemine contradicente* = no-one objects).  "Unanimous" means everyone is in favour. </pedant>

Comment: When I was in a student organization, we called votes like these "white ballot", where it passed quickly unless someone objected. Is there a difference?

Comment: @MartinBonner Agreed that the term is not pedant-friendly at an individual-word level, but I do believe "unanimous consent" is the standard terminology (at least for the US House and Senate)...it's unanimous in that everyone is in agreement that the motion may pass, not that they support the motion itself.

Comment: @Barmar It certainly sounds like the same thing in that you seem to be describing the process for unanimous consent, but I've never heard the term "white ballot" itself - not sure if that means it's a rare term or simply that I am ignorant.

Comment: The term isn't used in Robert's Rules of Order, but I found a [forum discussion](https://robertsrules.forumflash.com/topic/12894-what-is-a-white-ballot/) saying that it's often used to mean election by acclamation -- there's only one nominee and no one objects to electin them. I guess we expanded the use to other trivial votes.

Comment: @Barmar Ah, fun, you have investigated your own etymology! :) Glad you found an explanation

Comment: And someone there quoted a passage that says that acclamation is another word for unanimous consent, so I guess they *are* the same thing.

Answer (score 15):

A single lawmaker didn't really veto the bill.  What they "vetoed" was an instant, immediate, as-is passage of the legislation.  The process is called "unanimous consent" where the idea is that, if no one objects, the bill is passed. Fast and easy.

It can still pass, but it will have to go through the usual process including scheduled debate time for the bill, which will delay things quite a bit and would probably also see some changes to the bill through negotiations, relevant committee markups, riders, or via amendments.

Comment: There's an alternative to the usual long process. This is called suspension of the rules. It limits debate to about an hour, no amendments allowed, but requires a 2/3 majority to pass.

Comment: @pboss3010 - do they need a certain quorum to do that? At issue is the fact that Pelosi already ended the session and many members are on recess, which is why not being able to pass by unanimous consent is such a delay.

Comment: I believe it requires the usual quorum, but it does bypass the need to schedule a rules vote and such. So it's faster than regular legislation, but not as fast as passing something by unanimous consent.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet "do they need a certain quorum to do that" - According to the clear text of the Constitution (Article I Section 5) you need a majority to do anything but recess for the day or gather more members. In practice, the quorum rule is simply ignored if nobody present questions whether they have a quorum, even if there's a ridiculously small number of people there.